# Yii2 sending emails in the background

Tags: php, yii2

I have a `RESTful API` which registers a user and later sends an email to that user for account activation.
This works just fine but there is a great delay, since my code has to send the account activation email which sometimes takes time. How can I schedule jobs to run later or in the background for that task?

This is what I am doing currently:

```
actionCreateUser(){

   //HERE REGISTRATION

  if($model->save()){  //successifull registration

    //send email here which takes time
    if($emailsent){
      return ["data"=>true];
     }else{
        return ["data"=>false];
     }
   }

}
```

Then in the front-end I am checking the response of the `POST` request which is data(true or false).

How can I send the email in the background?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem not so long ago. The solution looks optimal for me.

1. You should install RabbitMQ message system. In Yii2 you can use `webtoucher/yii2-amqp` extension.
2. Define you own message component. Well, you can also redefine mailer component. Your component must send message to our RabbitMQ worker. In your web-application you have to use it instead of normal mailer.

```php
use Yii;
use yii\base\Component;
use yii\base\InvalidConfigException;
use yii\base\ErrorException;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

use webtoucher\amqp\components\Amqp;

class MessengerComponent extends Component
{

    protected $_recipient;
    protected $_subject;
    protected $_message_view;
    protected $_params;
    protected $_to;

    public function send()
    {

        $msg = [
            'to' => $this->_to,
            'message_view' => $this->_message_view,
            'subject' => $this->_subject,
            'params' => $this->_params,
        ];

        try {
            if(! YII_ENV_TEST)
                Yii::$app->amqp->send('send-message', 'send_message', $msg, Amqp::TYPE_DIRECT);
            return true;
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

3. Set up your RabbitMQ worker in your console application of Yii2. Note, that worker is a permanent process but not a request-like. So, you cannot declare mailer component and use it. You have to create mailer object only for a short time. For example, only for one mail. You can do this like that:

   ```php
   $mailer = Yii::createObject([
       'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
       'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
       'transport' => [
           'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
           'host' => 'mail.host.domain',
           'username' => 'mail username',
           'password' => 'mail passwork',
           'port' => '465',
           'encryption' => 'SSL',
       ],
   ]);

   $mailer
       ->compose(
           ['html' => $html, 'text' => $text],
           $this->params
       )
       ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['systemEmail'] => Yii::t('app', '{service} email title', [ 'service' => Yii::$app->name]
       ->setTo($this->email)
       ->setSubject($this->subject)
       ->send();
   ```

Comment: You don't have to install huge rabbitmq instance for a simple queue in a simple app. Database based queues (MySQL for example) will do fine too as well.

Comment: That's right. You don't have to use specialized tools. As alternative you can invent a new faulty and buggy instance of a bycicle. This is your choice. I just offer one of possible solutions, which I like.

Answer (score 1):

as thread implemntation is hard in php I suggest you to:
if you need to imediatly send your mail you can write action to send mail and just call it in your self action and don't wait for result and if user didn't got activation mail you can set an option for him to send it again.

you have to use cron jobs options too.by default yii don't implemented cronjobs 
you can use repository like [cron-manager](https://github.com/MUlt1mate/cron-manager) or something like this.just save your information in db and you can set every one minute your cron tab to run.

yii also is implementing queue but it's experimental yet.you can see it here : https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue

Comment: But in laravel there are queue workers https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues which do exactly that am wondring if the same can be implemented in yii2

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI by default yii don't have this option

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI you can use laravel queu in yii too https://github.com/illuminate/queue just import it to your project with composer also I updated my anser for yii2-queu

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI Yii queue is now completed, you can use it now